# Problem creating customer in Stripe which was deleted earler

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created customer with specific UUID via Stripe SDK in Java. I have deleted the customer from stripe dashboard and I am trying to create Customer with same UUID again. But Stripe create API returns error saying : `An error occurred: com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Customer already exists.; code: resource_already_exists; request-id: req_ijx6XztFJpbl9M`, but while creating subscription for same UUID, API returns : `com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such customer: <uuid>; code: resource_missing; request-id: req_WGL7FhMKf47uh6`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Customers are soft-deleted as noted in the API docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/delete

You cannot create a new customer with the same ID after deletion -- the error is correct. You can still retrieve the deleted customer directly, and you'll find it has `deleted=true`.

Using custom IDs is not recommended. If you're trying to align with internal IDs, using `metadata` is the suggested approach, and maintain the mapping to the Stripe-generated IDs in your system.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. One more related question: The customer created in Test mode remains in Live mode too ?

Comment: No, the objects in live vs test are separate. For some objects (like products) there is a process for copying to live, but this is not generally available.